# How do I search through regex matches in Python?

Tags: python, regex, switch-statement

I need to try a string against multiple (exclusive - meaning a string that matches one of them can't match any of the other) regexes, and execute a different piece of code depending on which one it matches. What I have currently is:

```
m = firstre.match(str)
if m:
    # Do something

m = secondre.match(str)
if m:
    # Do something else

m = thirdre.match(str)
if m:
    # Do something different from both
```

Apart from the ugliness, this code matches against all regexes even after it has matched one of them (say firstre), which is inefficient. I tried to use:

```
elif m = secondre.match(str)
```

but learnt that assignment is not allowed in if statements.

Is there an elegant way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def doit( s ):

    # with some side-effect on a
    a = [] 

    def f1( s, m ):
        a.append( 1 )
        print 'f1', a, s, m

    def f2( s, m ):
        a.append( 2 )
        print 'f2', a, s, m

    def f3( s, m ):
        a.append( 3 )
        print 'f3', a, s, m

    re1 = re.compile( 'one' )
    re2 = re.compile( 'two' )
    re3 = re.compile( 'three' )


    func_re_list = (
        ( f1, re1 ), 
        ( f2, re2 ), 
        ( f3, re3 ),
    )
    for myfunc, myre in func_re_list:
        m = myre.match( s )
        if m:
            myfunc( s, m )
            break


doit( 'one' ) 
doit( 'two' ) 
doit( 'three' )
```

Comment: +1 for pure pythonic awesomeness. Personally, I would put the list of tuples outside the for statement e.g. `match_functions = ((f1,re1),(f2,re2),..)` and do `for myfunc,myre in match_functions:`

Comment: Don't forget to add "break" to save trying to match against the rest of the list.

Comment: Edited with the suggestions of the comments plus real example.

Comment: I finally implemented a solution similar to this. In my case, I was able to refactor 3 of the 4 cases into a function. So I matched the first regex alone directly, and if it didn't match, went through the other 3 regexes, and called the function with the appropriate arguments. For calling the function with different arguments depending on the regex, I made a dict of (regex: (arg1, arg2)). The code is (IMHO atleast) more elegant than before now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a bit over engineering the solution, but you could combine them as a single regexp with named groups and see which group matched. This could be encapsulated as a helper class:

```
import re
class MultiRe(object):
    def __init__(self, **regexps):
        self.keys = regexps.keys()
        self.union_re = re.compile("|".join("(?P<%s>%s)" % kv for kv in regexps.items()))

    def match(self, string, *args):
        result = self.union_re.match(string, *args)
        if result:
            for key in self.keys:
                if result.group(key) is not None:
                    return key
```

Lookup would be like this:

```
multi_re = MultiRe(foo='fo+', bar='ba+r', baz='ba+z')
match = multi_re.match('baaz')
if match == 'foo':
     # one thing
elif match == 'bar':
     # some other thing
elif match == 'baz':
     # or this
else:
     # no match
```

Comment: This looks over engineering from my point of view. I don't find the code really easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

This is a good application for the undocumented but quite useful [re.Scanner](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/457664/) class.

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas, none of them good necessarily, but it might fit your code well:

How about putting the code in a separate function, i.e. `MatchRegex()`, which returns which regex it matched. That way, inside the function, you can use a return after you matched the first (or second) regex, meaning you lose the inefficiency.

Of course, you could always go with just nested `if` statements:

```
m = firstre.match(str)
if m:
   # Do something
else:
    m = secondre.match(str)
    ...
```

I really don't see any reason not to go with nested `if`s. They're very easy to understand and as efficient as you want. I'd go for them just for their simplicity.

Comment: what if there are few hundred regexes? code would be hardly readable for anything over 10-something.

Comment: @kibitzer: In that case, it makes sense to engineer a general solution. Or in the case where it is expected to grow to that. Not every time you have to write 3 nested if's.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
def do_first(str, res, actions):
  for re,action in zip(res, actions):
    m = re.match(str)
    if m:
      action(str)
      return
```

So, for example, say you've defined

```
def do_something_1(str):
  print "#1: %s" % str

def do_something_2(str):
  print "#2: %s" % str

def do_something_3(str):
  print "#3: %s" % str

firstre  = re.compile("foo")
secondre = re.compile("bar")
thirdre  = re.compile("baz")
```

Then call it with

```
do_first("baz",
         [firstre,        secondre,       thirdre],
         [do_something_1, do_something_2, do_something_3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Early returns, perhaps?

```
def doit(s):
    m = re1.match(s)
    if m:
        # Do something
        return

    m = re2.match(s)
    if m:
        # Do something else
        return

    ...
```

Ants Aasma's answer is good too. If you prefer less scaffolding you can write that out yourself using the [verbose regex syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.X).

```
re = re.compile(r'''(?x)    # set the verbose flag
    (?P<foo> fo+ )
  | (?P<bar> ba+r )
  | #...other alternatives...
''')

def doit(s):
    m = re.match(s)
    if m.group('foo'):
        # Do something
    elif m.group('bar'):
        # Do something else
    ...
```

I've done this a lot. It's fast and it works with `re.finditer`.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with an elif in case you just need a True/False out of regex matching:

```
if regex1.match(str):
    # do stuff
elif regex2.match(str):
    # and so on
```

Comment: I think he needs the return value from regex.match(str)